# How to caching Windows fact of ansible_fact to Redis?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have **ansible_fact** caching using **redis**.

It is well gathering to cache of redis for RHEL/AIX/HPUX and using ansible_fact of playbook.

**but, Windows fact is not caching to redis.**

**What problem? or What configuration will do?**

My ansible version is

```
[user]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /home/user/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user/utility/module']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Mar 26 2019, 22:13:06) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

My ansible.cfg is

```
  $ ansible-config dump --only-changed
  ANSIBLE_PIPELINING(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = True
  CACHE_PLUGIN(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = redis
  CACHE_PLUGIN_CONNECTION(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = localhost:6379:0
  CACHE_PLUGIN_TIMEOUT(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = 86100
  DEFAULT_FACT_PATH(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = /home/user/facts.d
  DEFAULT_GATHERING(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = smart
  DEFAULT_REMOTE_USER(/home/user/.ansible.cfg) = user
```

First playbook is well done (`gather_fact: yes`), gathering `ansible_memtotal_mb` for windows

```
- name: gather fact
  hosts: windows

  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: insertline
      lineinfile
        path: "fact.html"
        insertbefore: "</th></tr>"
        line: "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}"
```

Second playbook is problem (`gather_fact: no`), it is not use fact for cache data and fatal error occur.

```
- name: gather fact
  hosts: windows

  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: insertline
      lineinfile
        path: "fact.html"
        insertbefore: "</th></tr>"
        line: "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}"
```

The `ansible_memtotal_mb` **is not using cache data of redis**, despite of using cache for redis.

```
  TASK [(lineinfile) Save result DATA to HTML file. ****************************
  Tuesday 30 July 2019  10:41:40 +0900 (0:00:00.613)       0:00:07.639 **********
  fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an
 undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_memtotal_mb' is undefined
The error appears to be in '/home/user/systeminfo.yml': line 73, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
    - name: (lineinfile) Save result DATA to HTML file. [\"{{ WEB_DIR }}\"]
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}
Should be written as:
    with_items:
      - \"{{ foo }}\"
"}
```

Comment: You still need `gather_facts: yes`, even when using cached facts

Comment: @Mattp My ansible.cfg `gather fact` option is `smart`. I know if once caching ansible_fact, next playbook using the caching data. So my another platfrom like RHEL can use `ansible_fact` in caching data, dispite of `gather_facts: no`.

Comment: Has the timeout of the cache been exceeded? Setting `gather_facts: no` will not use the cache if it has timed out, and even with the `smart` setting will not update the cache. You are better off using `gather_facts: yes`, which will use the cache, and then update it if it is timed out.